# Running cupy on TX2

Tags: cupy

Recently I installed CUDA 10.0 and cupy on my tx2.
I read in an article where it says cupy is 10x faster than numpy.
So I ran this program:

```
### Numpy and CPU
s = time.time()
x_cpu = np.ones((100,100,100))
e = time.time()
print(e - s)
### CuPy and GPU
s = time.time()
x_gpu = cp.ones((100,100,100))
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
e = time.time()
print(e - s)
```

The results I got are very different. Numpy took only 0.00273, whereas Cupy took 0.6795s.
What could make cupy to be so slow. I installed cupy by:

```
sudo pip3 install cupy -vvv
```

Any clue would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The matrix size is quite small. CuPy is designed to work with large matrices where the overhead of data movement between the CPU and GPU can be effectively overlapped with actual GPU computation.

`cupy.ones` execution time in the GPU is very fast, in your example, the kernel launching overhead and device synchronization takes more time than the actual computation. If you increase the matrix size to `1000, 1000, 1000` you will be able to see actual speedup over numpy. Alternatively, you can repeat the calculations multiple times to hide the kernel launching overhead.

```
### Numpy and CPU
s = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    x_cpu = np.ones((100,100,100))
e = time.time()
print(e - s)
### CuPy and GPU
s = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    x_gpu = cp.ones((100,100,100))
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
e = time.time()
print(e - s)
```

Results are

```
3.421783447265625
0.7292115688323975
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I had to use Numba to force it to work faster.